# In App hosted WCF service throws 404 when Reverse Proxy

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have MVC application in which I have WCF service also. Its hosted in IIS. When I try to access the site and WCF service then I can get the service running successfully. But When I access the site through reverse proxy then I cannot access the WCF service but it throws 404 error. I have provided InBoundRule pattern as `(.*)`. Any help to this problem will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="OLAP.wcf.OlapClientService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebBindingHttp" contract="OLAP.wcf.IOlapClientService" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior">
    </endpoint>
    <!--<endpoint address=""
                      binding="webHttpBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="WebBindingHttps"
                      contract="OLAP.wcf.IOlapClientService" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior">
    </endpoint>-->
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WebBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WebBindingHttp">
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="WebBindingHttps">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
<client>
<endpoint address="http://100.100.100.100:8082/VibrantWS.svc/soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
</client>
```

Comment: What is your service configuration ?

Comment: @LaurentLequenne, Please see my edit.